# Basis for R3, when vectors are unknown

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the vectors be $(1, 1, 1), (1, x, 2)$ and $(1, 2, x)$.

Solve $x$ to find basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So,  $$ =\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\1&x&2\\ 1&2&x\end{bmatrix}$$

I get: $x^2 - 2x = 0$.

and then again $x = 2$

So my solution is that when $x$ is something else than $2$.

Am I doing this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2 - 2x = 0$ has *two* solutions, not just $x = 2$. Otherwise your approach and conclusion looks fine.

Some notational quirks, though. Your answer would, for instance, benefit from specifying that you're finding the determinant and setting it equal to $0$ in order to figure out whether the rows / columns of the matrix are linearly independent.

I would give this a (small) point deduction had this been on a test that I corrected because you're just writing down the vectors next to one another and then writing down some seemingly random equation. You have not connected these two things, which means that you haven't demonstrated beyond reasonable doubt that you understand the connection.

Answer (score 3):

We have $\det \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\1&x&2&\\ 1&2&x\end{bmatrix}=x^2-2x$,

then

$\det \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\1&x&2&\\ 1&2&x\end{bmatrix} \ne 0 \iff x \ne 0 $ and $x \ne 2$.

Conclusion: if $x \ne 0 $ and $x \ne 2$, then the vectors form a basis of $ \mathbb R^3$.